# What NSPredicate should I use to filter Core Data relationship in this case?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

[image]

Above is my Core Data relationships. This is a cocoa app with three NSTableView showing Genre, Album and Song. 
I want to filter GenreArrayController such that the Genre TableView only shows Genre name where Albums - Songs length is > 4.

When I Use Predicate on SongArrayController:

```
[_songArrayController setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 4"]];
```

The result is Genre and Album remain unfiltered but Songs table do get filtered. Is is possible to reach Genre - Album - Songs using NSPredicate on Genre.

**Am I doing this wrong way, can this be achieved by altering the Entities and their relations.**

Comment: I have not much experience with predicates, but you likely need to set the filter on the Genre ArrayController, and set something like "ALL albums.songs.length > 4". See for predicate syntax: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB

Answer (score 1):

You can combine predicates with `&&` or by using the more wordy compound predicates. You can access the *key paths*  of the relationships in your predicate via dot notation. Thus, to filter songs by genre:

```
NSPredicate(format: "length > 4 && album.genre = %@", genreObject)
```

or even

```
NSPredicate(format: "length > 4 && album.genre.name = %@", "Jazz")
```

Comment: I want to set predicate on GenreArrayController not on SongArrayController. When I try to set predicate using dot notion _ALL albums.songs.length > 4_ on Genre, I get an error: `[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x608000039c20> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: songs.lenght` **May be because I am filtering on relation sets object**

Comment: Do you want the total playing time of all songs of a single album?  Or all albums combined? Or *at least one* song > 4?

Comment: I wanted that Genre table only shows those  Genre name where  albums song count were greater the 4. I solved this using SubQuery. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery, I am able to filter `Genre` such that Genre table only shows genre, whose album contains numbers of songs greater than 4:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(albums, $x, ANY $x.songs.count > 4).@count != 0"];
```

Comment: "Genre whose album contains" is impossible. There can be more than one album.

Comment: @Mundi, Let there be two Genre, Rock and Jazz, each having 5 albums. What I want is if none of the albums in Rock or Jazz  has songs > 4, don't show that Genre name in the table. Above predicate worked. I should rename length to count for the attribute.